# Call laravel route from js file

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-5

I'm working with Laravel 5 for the first time, i have a blade where i include a JS file, when the blade calls the JS file. It doesn't recognize the URL :
this is how i call my URL in JS file :

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url : "{{URL::to('zone')}}",
        data: {'ma':$('select[name=ma]').val()},
        success: function(data) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

When i include this code in myBlade.blade.php it works fine but from the JS file i got the 403 error

Answer (score 18):

Blade doen't process JavaScript files, only those with `blade.php` extension

Solution may be to provide a global configuration object with a collection of routes you are interested in.

Assuming you have two separate files: `index.blade.php` plus `main.js`

1) `index.blade.php`

```
<script>
    // global app configuration object
    var config = {
        routes: {
            zone: "{{ URL::to('zone') }}"
        }
    };
</script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

2) `main.js`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    url : config.routes.zone,
    data: {'ma':$('select[name=ma]').val()},
    success: function(data) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: I think  var config = { routes: { zone: "{{ URL::to('zone') }}" } }; is true (use "{" instead of "[" after routes:)

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel And Also In codeigniter  simple Approch is
get the Base Url Path
Here I user

```
//code here
var path = {!! json_encode(url('/')) !!}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    url : path+'/zone',
    data: {'ma':$('select[name=ma]').val()},
    success: function(data) {
        ...
    }
});
```