# Laravel 5.2 - Autocomplete dropdown with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, routes

I'm tryng to code an autocomplete suggest input extracting a list from my database. I have a list of municipalities, but it doesn't work.

I tried like this:

ROUTES

```
Route::get('/crea-regalo', 'PostController@form');
Route::post('/crea-regalo', 'PostController@creaPost');
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('getdata', 'PostController@getData');
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function getData(Request $request) {

    $termn = $request->termn;

    // controllo
    $data = Municipality::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$termn.'%')
        ->take(10)
        ->get();
    $results = array();

    foreach ($data as $key => $v) {
        $results[]=['id' => $v->id, 'value' => $v->name];
    }

    return response()->json($results);
}
```

VIEW - FORM SECTION

```
<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="seller-Location">Municipality</label>
       <div class="col-md-8">
          <input type="text" name="municipality" placeholder="comune" id="searchname">
       </div>
 </div>
```

JS

```
$('#searchname').autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    autoFocus: true,
    source: '{{!!URL::route('getdata')!!}}',
    select: function(e, ui){ alter(ui);},
});
```

My console shows me an error like this:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier line 10 of my js file: 
>   source: '{{!!URL::route('getdata')!!}}',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{!! !!}}` isn't valid you could use `{{ }}` or `{!! !!}` instead.

Try to not mix JS with PHP code, and add a hidden input in your blade :

```
<input type="hidden" id="route-url" value="{{ route('getdata') }}">
//Or
<input type="hidden" id="route-url" value="{{ URL::route('getdata') }}">
```

**JS :**

```
$('#searchname').autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    autoFocus: true,
    source: $('#route-url').val(),
    select: function(e, ui){ alter(ui);},
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i fix the problem with hide input yes! my input show take 10 result as i want, but now termn doen't work well, it show always the first 10 items of my database for any keyword.

Comment: Good job.. now please make sure that the problem doesn't come from `alter(ui);` that should `alert(ui);`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{{route('getdata')}}`.

Also you can use php in js. I'm using it in my projects too and i didnt experience any harm from it.
Please also check if the route named "getdata" really does provide data in json.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend this library in order to solve this problem.

https://github.com/aaronlord/laroute

Answer (score 0):

Basically you cannot executed php code in a js file. |
This is a good answer: [Call laravel route from js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31072883/call-laravel-route-from-js-file)

Answer (score 0):

You need specify your url like

```
{{ url('getdata') }}
```

In any case your `{{!! !!}}` incorrect for blade templates. Did you mean `{!! !!}`?